# Neural networks - Difference between deep autoencoder and stacked autoencoder

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, autoencoders

As I understand it, the only difference between them is the way the two networks are trained. Deep autoencoders are trained in the same way as a single-layer neural network, while stacked autoencoders are trained with a greedy, layer-wise approach. Hugo Larochelle confirms this in the comment of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5ZYm_wJ37c). I wonder if this is the ONLY difference, any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Autoencoders with multiple hidden layers are called stacked autoencoders or deep autoencoders.*

They are the same thing.

*See Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and Tensorflow by Aurélien Géron for a good overview of the different types of autoencoders.